# Where is Jacob's Cabin? Where is the tire swing?

Tags: achievements, super-stick-golf

There are two achievements that I cannot find in Super Stick Golf.

In what course and what hole is Jacob's cabin?

In what course and what hole is the tire swing?

[image: SuperStick Golf Achievements]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacob's Cabin:

The Tire Swing:

Neither of these are especially intuitive to find, but the videos above should make it easier.